# git log abbreviated format length

Tags: git

I would like to get the SHA number from from GIT log in abbreviated format. This command will work:

```
git log -1 --format=%h
```

However, the default abbreviated format is 7 numbers in length.
Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For `git log`, the `--abbrev=<length>` parameter controls how long the output for `%h` and other abbreviated hashes is:

```
$ git log -1 --format=%h --abbrev=4
d157
```

I will also note that when using `-1` (or `--no-walk` which has the same effect in this particular case, but is more useful if you specify several commit identifiers), if all you want is the commit *hash*, using `git log` is overkill: `git rev-parse` will get you the hash.  For no obvious reason, the control knob for limiting `git rev-parse`'s commit IDs to a particular length is spelled `--short` rather than `--abbrev`; and `git rev-parse` requires that you spell out `HEAD` if you mean `HEAD`, so:

```
$ git rev-parse --short=4 HEAD
d157
```

#### How long or short can you go?

The longest is pretty long, currently 40 characters, probably 64 in the future.  The shortest you can *ever* go is four characters, which works in tiny repositories.  But the shortest you can go in some *particular repository* may be more than four characters.

For *output*, you can *ask for* the `--short` or `--abbrev` length to be any value you want.  Values that are too small or too big will be raised or lowered as needed.  (Note that in truly ancient versions of Git, it might show you four character hashes if you ask for them, even if they're too short to be unambiguous.  Current Git is smarter.)

When you supply a shortened raw hash ID of at least four characters yourself, though, if it's too short, you'll get an error like this one:

```
$ git rev-parse 1111
error: short SHA1 1111 is ambiguous
hint: The candidates are:
hint:   111116ea13 blob
hint:   1111f64dd9 blob
1111
fatal: ambiguous argument '1111': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Older versions of Git aren't as nice about their error messages; this one, which—if you read the `hint:` output lines—tells you that you need at least `11111` or `1111f` to pick one of the possible results, is from Git 2.27.0.

Since Git repositories grow over time, it's possible to use a very short hash ID early in the repository's lifetime, and later—say, in five years—discover that this short hash ID is now ambiguous.  The Linux kernel, for instance, is now up to the point where `git log --oneline` uses 12 characters for safety.  If you set a very short `--abbrev`, the `git log` output will have varying output hash sizes since each one gets extended to the necessary minimum:

```
$ git log --oneline -n 12 --abbrev=4
0f1a7b (HEAD -> master) timer-of: don't use conditional expression with mixed 'void' types
5021b9 Merge branch 'timers-urgent-for-linus' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip
714366 Merge branch 'sched-urgent-for-linus' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip
65aa35 Merge tag 'erofs-for-5.4-rc2-fixes' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/xiang/erofs
3fd57e7 char/random: Add a newline at the end of the file
```

Note how commit `0f1a7b3fac0583083ca19d4de47403511ced3521` was able to be shortened to `0f1a7b` (six characters), but commit `3fd57e7a9e66b9a8bcbf0560ff09e84d0b8de1bd` took seven (`3fd57e7`).  There are currently two objects with `3fd57e` as their first six hexadecimal digits of their hash IDs: one commit object and one tree object.  Over time, as more objects accumulate in the Linux kernel repository, even `3fd57e7` may become ambiguous.

Comment: Is there some specific GIT version needed for this to work? I've tried this command `git log -1 --format=%h --abbrev=6`, but it still returns 7 numbers. My GIT is 1.7.1

Comment: Yes, you need pretty much anything after 1.7.1, such as 1.7.1.1.  From the release notes for git 1.7.1.1: "git log --abbrev=$num --format='%h' ignored --abbrev=$num.

Comment: git will always display unique hashes.  Likely, in your repo you need 7 digits to uniquely identify the commits.  For instance, in my repo this `git log -5 --format=%h --abbrev=5` I see these:
    7ee2f
    89e8
    8cc16
    9f809
    d8ac

Comment: @DaveMontgomery: Git was recently (in 2.11) changed to automatically estimate the correct abbreviation length. Before then, the default was always 7 (but configurable, see `core.abbrev`). Some, but not all, code would extend beyond 7 if needed. See also [the 2.11 release notes](https://github.com/blog/2288-git-2-11-has-been-released).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the full hash with :

```
git log -1 --format=%H
```

You can also use an arbitrary number of chars with, for example for **6** digits:

```
git log -1 --format=%h --abbrev=6
```

### Edit 1:

To try how much saturated is the hash of the repo do the next:

```
git rev-list --all --abbrev=0 --abbrev-commit |
    awk '{ a[length] += 1 } END { for (len in a) print len, a[len] }'
```

I hope this helps :D

Comment: And how will this give the abbreviated hash with an arbitrary amount of characters like the OP requested? This will give the full hash which is not what was requested.

Comment: @Vampire I've edited and added the arbitrary option too.

Comment: @Fabricio: I've tried the second command, but the result is till 7 characters. Could it be GIT version dependant?

Comment: @ilya1725 then in this case your hash are totally saturated for 4 digits. Please try the command I've added to the answer to try how much saturated is the repo.