# default git log abbreviated format length

Tags: git

As already answered in [git log abbreviated format length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489841/git-log-abbreviated-format-length), the length of %h in git log can be changed.  However, my question is where is the **default** length stored?

I defined an git alias like this:

```
hist = log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
```

While I use `git hist` in two different repositories, one is showing 9 characters hash abbreviation, while the other is showing 7 characters, like most other repos.

Comment: It defaults to 7 but will show more characters if it has to in order to avoid ambiguous references. I think you should find that if you run a git log, grab one of those 9 character abbreviations, try `git show <7 first characters>` you will get a "ambiguous argument" error, you can then try with 8 and should get the same error, and with 9 you should be shown a commit.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen sounds very reasonable. However, I tried: `git log --pretty=format:%h |cut -b1-7|sort|uniq -c|grep -v "^\s*1 "`, did not find any duplicated entry...

Comment: @xrfang Try `git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects` to list all objects.

Comment: It's not just commit hashes that have to be unique, object hashes are used for trees, files, tags, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git will read the `core.abbrev` setting, if you've set it.  If not, or if you set it to the literal string `auto`, the default is to compute an *approximation*, dynamically, based on the number of objects—well, an approximation of that number—in the Git repository, of a length that will be suitable as [Lasse V. Karlsen noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098968/default-git-log-abbreviated-format-length#comment116862512_66098968) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098968/default-git-log-abbreviated-format-length#comment116863361_66098968).

[The `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) describes it this way:

> `core.abbrev`
>       Set the length object names are abbreviated to. If unspecified or set to "auto", an appropriate value is computed based on the approximate number of packed objects in your repository, which hopefully is enough for abbreviated object names to stay unique for some time. The minimum length is 4.

You mention that you have:

> ... two different repositories, one is showing 9 characters hash abbreviation [vs the more usual 7]

7 is the default minimum from the internal calculation (which uses a rough approximation of log2 of the approximated object count); the one with 9 must have many more objects in it than the others.  As the documentation says, the goal is to produce an abbreviation that will still work even once the repository grows, so if it's estimating 9 now, there's a good chance that 7 still works *now*, but maybe won't by next year.

Comment: by using cat-file, I found there are a few duplicated prefixes when length is 7, but no dup when it is 8.

Comment: Interesting. Note that the number of bits increases by 4 for each character added. If there are some (just a few) collisions at 7 characters = 28 bits and none at 8 = 32 bits, perhaps there are none at 29 or 30 bits. Git is already defaulting to 36 bits (9 characters). The probability of a collision rises rapidly with additional objects: this is the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) in action, but adding a bit halves the chance of a collision.