# Did the git-commit-hash change? (8 to 7 digits)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

Some of my CI/CD-Workflows depend on the commit-hash of git and I noticed one digit disappeared when I'm using:

```
echo $(git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1)
f7dc8fd
```

In the command-line to obtain the hash - notice the 7 digits. (Usually I save it for further usage)

On Gitlab the hash is different. 8 digits.

[image: The hash on Gitlab: Notice 8 digits]

It seems to be new, it used to be the same. How to sync it again? Should a different command or configuration be used?

Comment: Maybe the disappeared digita a pre-pended zero?

Comment: The commit hash didn't change. It's still 40-digit. The short hash you're refering to is but a convention, you can use any number (at least 4 though) of digits as long as it's unique in the repo.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca - you can see there are no zeros

Comment: I suspect the length of the abbreviated hash depends on the commit history. Mine are already 9-char.

Comment: @RomainValeri - I am aware it's still the "same" short-hash. I'm confused about the fact out of the sudden it changed. Is there a better way to obtain in in the command-line than `git log`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - they are 9 char when you execute `echo $(git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git log abbreviated format length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489841/git-log-abbreviated-format-length)

Comment: @EliasHolzmann - yes it does. Thank you. I will replace the `--pretty` with `git log -1 --format=%h --abbrev=8`